# Default cinnamon themes missing or not detected in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: themes, cinnamon

I just installed the cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 19.04. The cinnamon themes that were installed by default on 18.04 don't appear to be installed by default on 19.04. Where can I find them?

I'm specifically looking to use the Bluebird window borders and the Blue Menta desktop theme.

The theme settings application in cinnamon has an empty menu for window borders. Not even the active theme is listed there.

The only desktop theme that's present is the stock "cinnamon" theme.

[Here's a screenshot of the empty menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhPlA.jpg).

```
$ ls /usr/share/themes/
Adwaita  Adwaita-dark  Bluebird  Default  Emacs  HighContrast  Raleigh  Yaru  Yaru-dark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cinnamon package shipped in the Ubuntu 19.04 repositories is >= Cinnamon 3.8. This version of Cinnamon only supports window border themes which are metacity-3 compliant [1]. So, many of these window borders have gone away as they support metacity-1 or metacity-2; not metacity-3. A git repository has popped up adding metacity-3 compliance with simple instructions on reinstalling them [2].

> I'm specifically looking to use the Bluebird window borders

The Bluebird theme's upstream git repository has already been updated with metacity-3 compliance [3] but this change has not made its way into the Ubuntu package. I'm planning on sending a patch for the `bluebird-gtk-theme` Ubuntu package containing this fix.

> and the Blue Menta desktop theme.

This, and many of the other default Cinnamon themes I was referring to, can be installed with the `mate-themes` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/mate-themes/filelist).

[1] https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3557 Change log entry: "Titlebar themes are now restricted to metacity-3"

[2] https://github.com/smurphos/Window_Borders_Mint_19/

[3] https://github.com/shimmerproject/Bluebird/commit/12af472e008100153429c88eff8cd3d546b017e9